Facing issue in sending the message from the background.js to content-script.js in chrome extension
Although there are multiple articles on stack overflow articles that explain this, however, it has been of no help as of now. I want to send a message from my background.js file to the content-script.js file whenever I open the history tab on the browser. Below is the code for that:
background.js(which is a service-worker)
let currentTabURL = null;
let currentTabId = null;

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener((tab) => {
    currentTabURL = tab.pendingUrl;  
    currentTabId = tab.id;
    checkHistory();
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((windowInfo) => {
    currentTabId = windowInfo.tabId;
    chrome.tabs.get(currentTabId, (tab) => {
        if (tab.url) {
          currentTabURL = tab.url;
          checkHistory();
        }
    });
});

function checkHistory(){
  if(currentTabURL && currentTabURL.includes("://history/") && currentTabURL.endsWith("://history/")){
    console.log("History page opened");
    console.log("currentTabId: ", currentTabId);
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(currentTabId, {action: "checkHistory"});
  

  } else{
    console.log("History page not opened");
  }
}

content-script.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message,sender,sendResponse)=>{
  if(message.action==="checkHistory"){
    console.log("History page opened");
    return true;
  }
});

and everytime I receive the following error message:
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."
Thanks in advance

Content script can't run in a built-in UI page normally. What is the end goal? Maybe there's a workaround.

@wOxxOm the end goal is to remove the contents on the history tab and give a popup to the user with a password field.

You can redirect the tab to a different URL temporarily chrome.tabs.update({url: 'blocked.html'}) where blocked.html is in your extension, its blocked.js script would ask the password and then send a message to the background script telling it to redirect back to history this time allowing it.
